# Is there a way to exclude files not explicitly shared with the user from a script? ( aka files that are Shared with Everyone In Domain With The Link)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I'm trying to write a script that will return the name of every file that has been shared with the active user. However I'm having problems with the .getAccess() method.

**EDIT:**

So I've been tinkering with the code a little and it turns out that the code is breaking on files that are shared with "Everyone in the domain who has the link". So now the issue is that of avoiding files that are shared with everybody but are still popping up in the user's drive without having been explicitly shared with them.

Is there a way to say:

```
if (file.getAccess(user) == "VIEW" && file is explicitly shared with user)

or

&& file is not "Shared with everyone in the domain with the link"
```

**OLD QUESTION:**
When I use it on a file that was accessed from a specific ID, it works perfectly. 
For example:

```
var id = "1HoJbszb1uLF1RZpU_IPv3O648pIeYs4IWK2kbbQ4IaA";
var file = DriveApp.getFileById(x);

Logger.log(file.getAccess(user));
```

Log:

```
EDIT
```

However, if I try to iterate through every file in a user's drive, I will get an error "No Item with the given ID could be found, or you do not have permission to access it".

I've tried it these two ways:

```
  while (files.hasNext()){
    var raw = files.next();
    var id = raw.getId();
    var file = DriveApp.getFileById(id);
    if (file.getAccess(user) == "EDIT" ) Logger.log(file.getAccess(user));
  }
```

and:

```
  while (files.hasNext()){
    var file = files.next();
    if (file.getAccess(user) == "EDIT" ) Logger.log(file.getAccess(user)); 
  }
```

I get the same error trying it both ways. I've even checked to make sure that the .hasNext() method is working and to be sure when I ask the log to only list the names of each file it works fine as long as .getAccess() is never called (so no if statement).

```
while (files.hasNext()){
  var file = files.next();
  Logger.log(file.getName());
}
```

any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that `getAccess()` method - and the same applies to `getSharingAccess()` and `getSharingPermissions()` methods,- is only available to file owner and explicit editors. Files not shared with *Can edit* permission directly with a user throw the error you see.

There are several work-arounds available, though:

1. **If you need to only get files explicitly shared with the user with *"Can edit"* permission:**

   Check `getEditors().length` for a file - it will be 0 if the user
   does not have explicit *"Can edit"* permission to the file, and >0 if
   the user can edit the file.

   ```
   var f = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId);
   if ( f.getEditors().length ) {
     // this file has been explicitly shared with the user with "Can edit" permission
   }
   ```
2. **If you need to get files that the user has *"Can edit"* permission for, whether those files were shared explicitly with the user or
   not:**

   First, enable *Drive API* in your script's Advanced Google services
   (under menu Resources) AND in Google Developers Console - [more
   details on enabling advanced services can be found
   here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services).
   After that, you can check the user's permission to the file by
   checking `File.userPermission.role` property:

   ```
   var f = Drive.Files.get(fileId); // requires Drive API in Advanced Google services
   var up = f.userPermission;
   if (up.role=='writer') {
     // 'writer' = user has Edit permission to the file
   }
   ```

   `File.userPermission.role` will be ***writer*** for files user has
   *"Can edit"* permissions to, whichever way the files were shared with the
   user (explicitly, via group/domain membership or for public files). Other possible values are ***reader*** (user has *"Can view"* or
   *"Can comment"* permissions to the file) and ***owner*** (the user is the owner/creator of the file). [More info on `userPermission` property
   here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions#resource).